# Run application from browser

Tags: c#, url, browser, web-applications, launch

I could not find any information about this. I am sure there is a term for this type of applications, but I have no idea where to look. That's why I decided to ask here.

So there are a few websites where you hover over a link or button it says something like **`application:xyz`** where **`application`** usually is the name application to run, and the **`xyz`** are the parameters or something.

An example is all the torrent links. If you hover over a link there it says
**`magnet:?somethingxxxxxxxxxxxx`** how can I bind my own custom application to a certain URL?

Let's say I have a C# application I call **`Musiclist`**. I want to make URLs like: **`musiclist:?song=hey123`**

And when I click it in my browser, it opens the application.

I really could not find anything about this with some examples, or how I pass those variables in with the **`:?`** in the link, so that's why I cannot provide any code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's called [**a protocol or a URI Scheme**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx).

This is defined in the registry, so you'd have to add the correct values there:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    <protocol>
        (Default) = "URL:<protocol name>"
        URL Protocol = ""
        DefaultIcon
            (Default) = "<path to your application>,<icon index>"
        shell
            open
                command
                    (Default) = "<path to your application>" "%1"
```

In your case this could for example be:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    musiclist
        (Default) = "URL:Music list protocol"
        URL Protocol = ""
        DefaultIcon
            (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Musiclist\musiclist.exe,0"
        shell
            open
                command
                    (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Musiclist\musiclist.exe" "%1"
```

Everything after the colon (`:`) will be passed to your application as (a) Command Line Argument(s).

Comment: But how can I add multiple different parameters at the end of the url? How do I make my application act different depending on that? Like ?:artist, or ?:songname or something else. Could be anything really. is it some code inside my application Form_Load like `if (parameter == 'artist') { //something } else if (parameter == 'song') { //play song }`

Comment: @TibiaPlayer : That would be for your application to parse. You could separate each parameter with a `?` and in your app split by that. For example: `musiclist:?artist=James?songname=123?group=Something`.

Comment: Do you know any videos of this stuff for c#? I tried to find some in youtube but couldn't find anything called c# protocols, or c# uri scheme

Comment: @TibiaPlayer : Why do you need a video? Just add those values to the registry, the rest is about parsing command line parameters (and for that you'd use for example `String.Split()`). [**Read, write and delete from registry with C#**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

Comment: alright thanks, I'll try figure it out. I'm quite new to C# though so still learning. That's why I prefer videos where they explain things step by step :P

Comment: @TibiaPlayer : Well you asked a question and got an answer to it. You'd have to ask a new one for that (although you should do some own attempts first, because that's what this community wants :) ). But I can give you a step in the right direction: `String.Split()` -> Array, `foreach`-loop on array + if-statement in the loop.